# Can't push the iOS code on git

Tags: ios, xcode, git, macos, terminal

It was working before some days and now while pushing the code, I am getting following on terminal.

> Counting objects: 218, done.
>   Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
>   Compressing objects: 100% (218/218), done.
>   Writing objects: 100% (218/218), 485.32 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
>   Total 218 (delta 93), reused 0 (delta 0)
>   error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 401
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>   Everything up-to-date

I am not getting this why, its happening. After some googling I tried to increase buffer size and check but still having same problem.
Can somebody help here? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the http error code 401 tells that you are not authorized. did your credential change?

Comment: Yes, recently I changed my password, but with the same password I can able to login on web but facing this issue with terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase the Git buffer size:

> git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400